# Get external IP address on Universal Windows 10

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am searching for a solution to get the external IP address on Universal Windows 10. I already found how to get local address:

```
public static string getLocalIpAdress()
{
    foreach (HostName localHostName in NetworkInformation.GetHostNames())
    {
        if (localHostName.IPInformation != null)
        {
            if (localHostName.Type == HostNameType.Ipv4)
            {
                return localHostName.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    return "unknown adress";
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that the external address may well be a router, and hide many devices (like an entire office or household) - as a result whilst you can get it, it's not going to be that useful for routing traffic

Comment: Also bear in mind that in some situations, you may have differing IP addresses based on protocol (e.g. if a HTTP proxy is intercepting your traffic), or destination (e.g. if you're on a WAN that has multiple peering points with the wider Internet)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The single reliable solution is to use your WebApi back-end to detect user's IP address. Or you can use any public API. For example https://api.ipify.org/

```
var myIp = await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync("https://api.ipify.org/");
```

Comment: It actually is the ONLY solution - there is no reliable way to ask for the external IP From the inside.